# G++ confuses prototype of function returning struct as struct initializer

Tags: c++, struct

When compiling the project I get the following error:

```
drawplant.h: In function 'Matrix3f current_matrix()':
drawplant.h:26:1: error: only constructors take member initializers
 Matrix3f mmmult(Matrix3f, Matrix3f);
```

Here is drawplant.h:

```
#ifndef _DRAWPLANT_H_
#define _DRAWPLANT_H_

/* Functions implemented in drawplant.cpp */

#define PI 3.14159265358


struct Vector3f{
    GLdouble v[4];
} typedef Vector3f;

struct Matrix3f{
    GLdouble m[16];
} typedef Matrix3f;

extern int depth;

void drawPlant();
void push();
void pop();
//void rotate(GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble);
//void translate(GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble);
//void scale(GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble);
Matrix3f current_matrix(void):
Matrix3f mmmult(Matrix3f, Matrix3f);
Vector3f mvmult(Matrix3f, Vector3f);
#endif  /* _DRAWPLANT_H_ */
```

Comment: you made a typo.  : should be ;  how embarrassing is that? :p

Comment: @thang: you should post that as an answer :-) it's the correct answer

Comment: another good example of misleading compiler error message from g++

Comment: Glad you could get some help with your problem, but this is off-topic as it was caused by a simple typographic error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
Matrix3f current_matrix(void):
```

to

```
Matrix3f current_matrix(void);
```

Notice the semicolon at the end.

Comment: Thanks. That's embarrassing. It's been a long day.